# Sending sms from Google sheets, error: no recipient

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First time using script this is what I have after a couple hours.

I'm setting up a daily text blast which in testing works but I get this error Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient
    at sendtext(Code:8:9)
Here's my sheet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS5c2.png

[image]
And my code:

```
function sendtext() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Word-a-Day");
  var lrow=sh.getLastRow()
  for(var i=2;i<=lrow;i++) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(sh.getRange(i,2).getValue(), "Khmer Word-A-Day", sh.getRange(2, 3).getValue()) 
  }
}
```

The test texts goes through but I get the an error every time. Is this because of using the sms gateway?

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the first parameter is wrong or null?  Can you provide an image of your sheet.

Comment: Since I'm new I can't embed the image, link provided. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendtext() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Word-a-Day");
  var lrow=sh.getLastRow(); 
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vs=rg.getValues();
  var q=MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  for(var i=0;i<vs.length;i++) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(vs[i][0], "Khmer Word-A-Day", vs[i][1]);
    //Utilities.sleep(5000);//Perhaps you need a delay here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found random space in a cell in the text gateway column so it was throwing an error. Thanks for the help.